# In Chrome OS, Bash won't execute my script. How do I get Bash to run my script?

Tags: bash, chrome-os

I have a `foo.sh` file in my current directory. If I try to run `./foo.sh`, I get:

```
-bash: ./foo.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

But if I run `/bin/sh ./foo.sh` then it runs fine.

How can I fix this so I can just run `./foo.sh` and it automatically runs it with /bin/sh?

Edit: Okay, this is Chrome OS and this particular folder is mounted with `noexec`. Apparently that foils the ability to just run `./foo.sh`; but **why?** Why can I still run `sh foo.sh` to achieve the exact same thing? What security, then, does `noexec` give?

Comment: security through obscurity

Comment: Did you try if running ". foo.sh" works?

Comment: @DanieleTesta This question is an ancient relic from a time long past. I was using a Google Cr-48, one of the first chromebooks, running a pretty early (but stable) version of ChromeOS. We've come a long way since then and I don't think this question would apply to the latest ChromeOS versions, but I haven't used it to say for sure. Anyway I think your variation would also have worked but one should test it before saying for sure. I am still unclear on exactly how `noexec` works its magic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `noexec` flag will appropriately apply to scripts, because that would be the "expected" behavior.

However, setting `noexec` only stops people who don't know enough about what they're doing. When you run `sh foo.sh` you're actually running `sh` from its default location (probably `/bin`) which is not on a filesystem mounted with `noexec`.

You can even get around `noexec` for regular binary files by invoking `ld` directly.

```
cp /bin/bash $HOME
/lib/ld-2.7.so $HOME/bash
```

This will run bash, regardless of whether or not it's on a filesystem mounted with `noexec`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `ld.so` (clever)

Comment: I tried your two commands; "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" - due to sh being copied but bash being run. So then I tried `/lib/ld-2.10.1.so $HOME/sh` and it returned another error while loading shared libraries: `/home/chronos/user/sh: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted`. I'm not sure if what you said was untrue, or if something else is interfering. For example, / is mounted as read-only.

Comment: Well, I couldn't say for certain because I don't have a copy of ChromeOS to try with. I'm fairly confident that it can work with some modification but without being able to try it myself I don't know what that might be.

Comment: Oh well, I'd like to think that it's because Chrome OS is properly locked down. It does seem to be pretty secure but I guess we'll see over time!

Comment: I know how `ld` worked but never made that connection. Thanks for teaching me something today! - though AFAICT this will fail to execute a statically linked binary.

Comment: There's a difference between `ld` and `ld.so`. `ld` is a linker used in linking object code to form a binary when compiling, while `ld.so` is the run-time linker performing a similar action when executing a program. The linker referred to here is the run-time linker.

Answer (score 5):

You can also get this error (or a very, very similar message) if you try to execute a file with MS-DOS 2-byte (carriage-return linefeed) line endings.

Vim is so smart these days, that it doesn't neccessarily show you the carriage returns as '^M'.  So you can get fooled if you don't check what Vim thinks the "file format" is and just rely on the on-screen-appearance.

In this case the "#!/bin/sh^M" causes the kernel to try to find "/bin/sh^M", which it can't. Bad interpreter, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option to run the script or program from a USB stick (or other removable media), you can try unmounting and manually re-mounting it:

1. Plug in USB stick
2. Find USB stick device with `$ mount`
3. Take note of it; let's assume it is `/dev/sdb1`
4. Unmount USB stick:

   ```
   $ cd /media/removable

   $ sudo umount mountpoint
   ```

Finally, re-mount USB stick:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 mountpoint
```

With mountpoint the USB stick's mount name

Answer (score 1):

For system security reasons on ChromeOS/ChromiumOS certain folders are marked `noexec` and you either need to remount with the command below, or use an alternate path that doesn't have `noexec` set, like the second example.

These commands assume you are at least in developer mode and have access to the `shell` with `chronos@localhost / $` and not just `crosh>` and know the sudo password.

```
sudo mount -i -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user/
```

The more sustainable method that should survive an upgrade because Google reserves most of `/usr/local` for developers:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/ && sudo chown -R chronos: /usr/local/bin/
cp ${HOME}/Downloads/foo.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

The additional benefit of putting things here is that it is in the `$PATH` already (try `echo $PATH` to confirm this) so you don't need to use the full path to run scripts or binaries that are in `/usr/local/bin` and have had `chmod +x` run on them.

Comment: Hi, welcome on the Unix SE! Note, single-command answers aren't considered very HQ here. I suggest to explain, what are you doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. My problem was with the SD card. This worked for me, and it's much simpler than the other answers here. I learned it from [Crouton issue #928](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/928).

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/removable/SD\ Card
```

Note that you have to use the mount point, not the device (/dev/mmcblk1p1). Same thing for USB (/dev/sdb1) in your case. Only the mount point is different:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/removable/USB\ Drive
```

You'll know it had the desired effect because "noexec" will disappear from the mount options when you query.