# How to run a shell script (bash) on a chromebook?

Tags: bash, shell-script, chrome-os, chrome-book

I have a shell script and I need to run it in order to connect to a remote ubuntu linux machine having encrypted HDD, in order to enter the passphrase. There's a shell script for this, but I have a chromebook most of the time when away. Can this be done from a chromebook?

I have already seen chrome extensions like mosh.

Answer (score 5):

The shell prompt is available in Chrome OS.  The instructions for accessing it are available here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/developer_mode.md.

If the script happens to be stored on a filesystem mounted with `noexec` (such as your home directory), then the script may need to be called with `sh` explicitly:

```
/bin/sh foo.sh
```

More information:  [In Chrome OS, Bash won't execute my script. How do I get Bash to run my script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/bash-wont-execute-files).

Comment: Hey thanks, I already found the solution and have already put my laptop in dev mode :) .

Answer (score 0):

###### 1. Enable developer mode

- Holding Esc + Refresh(F3) + pressing Power button --> release Power Button.
  This is `recovery mode`
- inside **recovery mode,** press **Ctrl  + D**. this turns on `developer mode`

###### 2. Get the Command Prompt

- either with:

  - **Ctrl** + **Alt** + →[ right-arrow ]
  - **Ctrl + Alt + T**

###### 3. Remount folder with exec permission

For system security reasons on **ChromeOS** certain folders are marked **no-exec** so **remount** with:

```bsh
sudo mount -i -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user/
```

- this step is usually what let you run **bash scripts**, exec **programs** you installed like `meteor`. Also, could be for external devices:

```bsh
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/removable/SD\ Card
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/removable/USB\ Drive
```

- **noexec** will disappear from the mount options when you query.